# First and second (numerical) derivative of density function?

Tags: r, distribution, numerical-methods

What is the most accurate way to compute F''(x) and F'''(x) for a range of values of x if only F'(x) is known to `R` (for example take F to be the Gaussian)?

Comment: `x = seq(-2, 2, length.out = 1000); diff(dnorm(x)) / diff(x)` for F'', rinse and repeat for F'''?

Comment: if this the most prceise? I would have though  `deriv` could do better?

Comment: The most precise would be to do it analytically, which isn't so bad for a Gaussian distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `D()`function to compute F''(x) if you know F'(x). For example if F'(x) is `4*x^3` then to calculate the second derivative (F''(x)) you enter:

```
> D(expression(4*x^3), 'x')
 4 * (3 * x^2)
```

To calculate F'''(x) you do the same thing with the given output (`4 * (3 * x^2)`).